# What is the action performed by the "Quit" option in application launcher icon?

Tags: unity, launcher, dbus

**TL;DR** what command/dbus method /action is being called by the `Quit` action in each launcher icon ?

I've been reading the source for Unity 7 over the last few days and found a few lines of code that suggest there may be dbus method that can be called to gracefully kill all windows of an application:

```
  /* Quit */
  menu_item = dbusmenu_menuitem_new();
  dbusmenu_menuitem_property_set(menu_item, DBUSMENU_MENUITEM_PROP_LABEL, _("Quit"));
  dbusmenu_menuitem_property_set_bool(menu_item, DBUSMENU_MENUITEM_PROP_ENABLED, true);
  dbusmenu_menuitem_property_set_bool(menu_item, DBUSMENU_MENUITEM_PROP_VISIBLE, true);

  _gsignals.Add<void, DbusmenuMenuitem*, unsigned>(menu_item, DBUSMENU_MENUITEM_SIGNAL_ITEM_ACTIVATED,
    [this] (DbusmenuMenuitem*, unsigned) {
      Quit()
```

(taken from `unity-7.2.0+14.04.20140416/launcher/ApplicationLauncherIcon.cpp`)

For some time it's been a difficulty communicating with the X server. Sending `HUP` or any other signal doesn't close a GUI window gracefully. Such tools as `xdotool` and `wmctrl` do communicate with the X but on the C programming level.

What the code above suggests is that there is a simpler way to programmatically  close windows in a graceful way , without need to install external tools like `wmctrl` or `xdotool`. That's precisely what I am after in this question.

Comment: This question will have a bounty offered as soon as it's available

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you trying to find out how to send a similar D-Bus message, i.e. how to make a command `sendquit` that sends a similar quit notification? What parameter would it take?

Comment: @Gilles  Essentially , yes, I am trying to find the same D-Bus message.  I've been trying to use `dbus-monitor` and the right click an icon on Unity Launcher, then click "Quit" for the running program. So far I've not seen any event that would correspond to the "Quit" action.

Comment: What makes you think it's sending a D-Bus message then?

Comment: @Gilles that's my assumption, at least, based on the code in `.cpp` file I've mentioned from unity source

Comment: Essentially , I want to know what does that option do under the hood.  I want to be able to perform that same action

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand that code it creates a menu item and connects it via DBus to `void ApplicationLauncherIcon::Quit()` (same file).

This basically calls

```
void AppWindow::Quit() const
{
  WindowManager::Default().Close(window_id());
}
```

(file `unity-shared/BamfApplicationManager.cpp`) for each window that belongs to the launcher icon, which essentially does the same as `wmctrl -i -c window_id`

Comment: That *seems* to be close. I can find a `Quit` method for `org.ayatana.bamf` interface, but it only flashes all the icons on the launcher, as if windows quit. Then the active ones highlight again. Specifically , this `qdbus org.ayatana.bamf /org/ayatana/bamf/control org.ayatana.bamf.control.Quit`

Comment: @Serg: That quits (and then restarts)  bamfdaemon. The menu item just sends a message via D-Bus that its state has been changed and an event handler for that event calls the `Quit` method without using D-Bus.

Comment: As [d-bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus) is an implementation of IPC (inter process communication) it us up to the receiver to a) register to d-bus, b)  receive d-bus messages and finaly c) do a graceful shutdown on a specific message.